# Why is my XAMPP Apache only showing a blank page?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, apache2

I've got a few Zend projects on my xampp, but if I'm going to the public directory to show the project, there's only a blank, white page. Testscripts with just an echo or the xampp tools are working fine. The xampp installation is fresh, I didn't change anything and even the Windows 7 installation is new. Also PHP errors and exceptions are showing, if there are any, this is what is written in the error.log:

```
[Fri May 03 15:49:37.072758 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5784:tid 256] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri May 03 15:49:38.945865 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5784:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 03 15:49:38.946865 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5784:tid 256] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Fri May 03 15:49:38.946865 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5784:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri May 03 15:49:38.952865 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5784:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5428
[Fri May 03 15:49:44.385176 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 5428:tid 268] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri May 03 15:49:44.702194 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5428:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

just notices and warnings, the php error log is empty. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by *going to the public directory to show the project*? Are you running the application?

Comment: Yes, i mean the public directory of the zend project to run the zend application. It should show the index page of the site.

Comment: did you put your projects in the document root so they can be accessed via the localhost or better yet did you define a vhost for each project and then edit your hosts file? Please detail your setup a little better. The big one "Is mod_rewrite enabled"?